# NAs when calculating the mean of raster values per polygon using R (stars & sf)

Tags: raster, r, sf, stars

I am trying to get the mean NDVI value for tree clusters (I've calculated them using DBSCAN) using stars and sf but, I'm getting a lot of NA values, which they don't appear if I use the Zonal Statistics tool in QGIS. The code I'm using is the following.

```
library(stars)
library(sf)
# read raster

bcn_normalitzat <- stars::read_stars("./raster_normalitzat.tiff")
cluster_polygons <- st_read("./tree_clusters.geojson")
cluster_polygons <- cluster_polygons |> mutate("geometry" = st_make_valid(geometry))


clusters_ndvi <- aggregate(bcn_normalitzat, cluster_polygons, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE) |> 
  st_as_sf() |> 
  rename("ndvi" = "raster_normalitzat.tiff.V1") |> 
  select("ndvi", "geometry")
```

You can download the raster data from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15tO6imf_h-5wLk9vuWFgJjVJBt6Uve14/view?usp=sharing) and the polygon layer from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zjB2OePiEv3AjtEu0QjVjKlreGBbyw2t/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a map in QGIS of your raster and polygons with green coloured where the value isn't NA and purple where it is, plus the cell centres as dots:

[image]

`aggregate` is only sampling if the polygon overlaps a cell centre.

The help for `stars::aggregate` suggest using `exact=TRUE` and `coverage_fraction` which doesn't appear to be a function from `stars` and there's no example using it.

A naive test just fails with an unhelpful error message:

```
> aggregate(bcn_normalitzat, cluster_polygons[1:10,], FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, exact=TRUE)
Error in CPP_coverage_fraction(x, wkb, crop) : 
  Cannot convert object to a function: [type=NULL; target=CLOSXP, SPECIALSXP, or BUILTINSXP].
```

There is a `coverage_fraction` function in the `exactextractr` which is the fastest package I know for grid/poly overlays and I suggest you use that in future. It doesn't seem to work with stars rasters but is happy with `terra` rasters which work fine with your data.

Your data is a mix of polygons and lines and points which further complicates things. Points are dimension=0 and lines are dimension=1:

```
> table(st_dimension(cluster_polygons))

   0    1    2 
  12    7 4918
```

If I strip those out it takes about ten seconds to do a full polygon/grid-square intersection:

```
cpoly = cluster_polygons[st_dimension(cluster_polygons)==2,]
library(terra)
library(exactextractr)
r = rast("./raster_normalitzat.tiff")
ee = exact_extract(r, cpoly)
  |======================================================================| 100%
>
```

Note this returns a list of data frames of values and coverage fractions giving how much of the cell the polygon has covered, from this you can compute any weighted value you need based on whether your measurement is intrinsic or extrinsic.

```
> ee[[1]]
  raster_normalitzat_1 raster_normalitzat_2 raster_normalitzat_3
1                  151                  151                  151
2                  151                  151                  151
3                  177                  177                  177
4                  144                  144                  144
5                  120                  120                  120
6                  161                  161                  161
  raster_normalitzat_4 coverage_fraction
1                  255       0.088045530
2                  255       0.077159368
3                  255       0.366799265
4                  255       0.410003424
5                  255       0.001292809
6                  255       0.016486300
>
```

Basically the answer is "don't use `aggregate`, use the `exactextractr` package".

Comment: Since I am allowed to comment now, let me post this here: `stars` suggests `exactextractr`, so when using `stars::aggregate(..., exact=TRUE)` I'd expect `exactextractr::coverage_fraction()` to be called instead internally. However, the following example does not work for me either but a different error is thrown: `aggregate(bcn_normalitzat, cluster_polygons[1:10,], FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE, exact=TRUE)` leads to `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : argument "to" is missing, with no default`. What are we missing?